# Dynamodb table with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-dynamodb

I have "books" table in amazon-Dynamodb, which is having 287 items and 97kb in size.
i tried to load my all data from books table through ruby on rails coding(controller). but its loading time is very slow. and sometimes it shows nothing because of time out situation. so please help me to improve the knowledge in dynamo db table handling.

Comment: Are you loading items individually? Are you getting throttled? What is your provisioned throughput on your table and how much of it is being used when you run your code? Are any of the items created? Please show some code and add more details.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Dynamodb it's a key value store database, you shouldn't pull out "all the data" because it's designed to pull one record or a few records with scan command.

Can you describe your problem and why you need to use Dynamodb ?

Comment: Yeah, But i put some code in my model, to get all items from table. its working fine. but loading time is very slow. why? some times it is working for 50 data. but when comes to large data, it takes to much of time to load. how to resolve this?

Comment: I said it you shouldn't, not you couldn't. I've explained to you, it's slow because DynamoDB is a key-value store, and a key value store it's designed to pull items from a specific key (and in the case of DynamoDB key and range-key or both), not to pull all the data in the table.

Comment: @letz i was facing same issue but when implemented limit then i am able to get. But i have another issue like i want to get table description using ruby script but not finding way. Could you please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the DynamoDB parallel scan API: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#QueryAndScanParallelScan

Scan is expensive because you are reading back all of the items in your table (consuming read capacity for each one), but if you really want to read back all of the items in the table, this is probably the most efficient solution.

DynamoDB pages scan results because each result can contain up to 1MB. The reason this can take some time is because you need to receive the previous page and get the lastEvaluatedKey parameter to make the call for the next page. The parallel scan API breaks the hash key space into segments that can be processed independently (still may require multiple pages). By processing each scan segment in a separate thread, you should be able to achieve much more parallelism and less total time to retrieve the items in your table.

At some point you may also consume all of your provisioned throughput, resulting in throttling. To mitigate this, you can increase your provisioned throughput, or implement self-throttling with a rate-limiter.